# Python: lxml xpath give unwanted data at the begining

Tags: python, xpath

I want to get the part started from 
    `Straits Times Index (STI) (STI.SI)` to the end of it. It is a long list.

```
<option value="nyse_mkt" class="{access_allowed : true}">NYSE Mkts</option>
<option value="world" class="{access_allowed : true}">World</option></select><select class="validate-selection" id="counter_sgx" name="counter"><option value="">-- Select Counter --</option>
<option value="STI.SI">Straits Times Index (STI) (STI.SI)</option>
<option value="ADLN.SI">ADLN (ADLN.SI)</option>
<option value="SGXCN2.SI">CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) (SGXCN2.SI)</option>
<option value="SGXCN7.SI">CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX (SGXCN7.SI)</option>
<option value="SGXCN6.SI">CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX (SGXCN6.SI)</option>
<option value="SGXCN15.SI">FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX (SGXCN15.SI)</option>
<option value="SGXCN13.SI">FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX (SGXCN13.SI)</option>
<option value="SGXCN14.SI">FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX (SGXCN14.SI)</option>
<option value="FSTAS.SI">FTSE ST All-Share Index (FSTAS.SI)</option>
```

However, I only manage to get some unused data at the beginning.

```
['SGX',
 'Bursa',
 'HKEx',
 'SET',
 'IDX',
 'ASX',
 'NYSE',
 'NASDAQ',
 'NYSE Mkts',
 'World',
 '-- Select Counter --',
 'Straits Times Index (STI) (STI.SI)',
 'ADLN (ADLN.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) (SGXCN2.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX (SGXCN7.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX (SGXCN6.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX (SGXCN15.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX (SGXCN13.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX (SGXCN14.SI)',
 'FTSE ST All-Share Index (FSTAS.SI)']
```

My code is:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=STI.SI')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tree.xpath('//option[@value]/text()')
```

example output I need is

```
Straits Times Index (STI) (STI.SI)
ADLN (ADLN.SI)
CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) (SGXCN2.SI)
...
FTSE ST All-Share Index (FSTAS.SI)
```

Comment: Your XPath has closing paren without corresponding opening paren : `@class="validate-selection")`

Comment: @har07, it return blank now. Let me edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to build a XPath that does the following:

1. Find the element with a given value (`STI.SI`),
2. Give me all its `option` siblings' texts.

For the first part, in your code you only get the options which have a value (almost all of them), you have to modify it as this: `option[@value="STI.SI"]`.

For the second part, you have to follow all option siblings: `following-sibling::option`.

Wrapping all together:

```
tree.xpath('//option[@value="STI.SI"]/following-sibling::option/text()')
```

will give you all the siblings after the one you specified. But since you wanted also that included, you should do this:

```
tree.xpath('//option[@value=""]/following-sibling::option/text()')
```

because the option before the one with value `STI.SI` has a blank value. Careful with this, because I haven't tested what would happen with multiple blank values in the `select`.